# Taylor expansion of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I come across this Taylor expansion of integral,

$\int_{v-h}^v \rho\left(v^{\prime}\right) d v^{\prime} \approx h \rho-\frac{1}{2} h^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \rho$
when $h → 0$

I am a bit confused on how Taylor expansion should be done on an integral. I tried to think of the integral as summing the area under $\rho(v)$, but it looks like the approximation should be $h\rho(v)+\frac{1}{2}h\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\rho$.

Any help?

Comment: Taylor expand the integrand and then integrate: $\rho(v’) \approx \rho(v)+\rho’(v)(v’-v)$.

Comment: Expand $\rho(v')$ in a Taylor series about $v-h$ and then do a term by term integration and apply the limits.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Thanks.